# jQuery DataTables Getting selected row values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable.I done it using http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html
Now I want to get selected row values ids

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
} );
} );
```

And HTML Code:

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
         </table>
```

Now I am able to get selected no.of.rows.Now I want to get selected row Ids.Can anyone guide me to achieve it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can iterate over the row data

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
        return item[0]
    });
    console.log(ids)
    alert(table.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f4bppa43/)

Comment: Hi Is there any way to make some rows selected by default?

Comment: This method will get the data even if the column is hidden. How can you get the row data for visible columns?

Comment: Is it possible to get the corresponding tr jquery object ?

Answer (score 10):

More a comment than an answer - but I cannot add comments yet: Thanks for your help, the count was the easy part. Just for others that might come here. I hope that it will save you some time.

It took me a while to get the **attributes** from the rows and to understand how to access them from the **data()** Object (that the data() is an Array and the Attributes can be read by adding them with a dot and not with brackets:

```
$('#button').click( function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows('.selected').data().length; i++) { 
       console.log( table.rows('.selected').data()[i].attributeNameFromYourself);
    }
} );
```

(by the way: I get the data for my table using AJAX and JSON)

Comment: I have similar requirement but in my case my ID is hidden "bVisible": false? so how can I get the hidden column value of the selected row?

Comment: Hmm, the column should still be in the data() Object as it is just hidden. Can't you iterate over the data? I was looking for the hidden objectId in my dataset and is looked like this: `var oSelectRows = oMyTable.rows(".selected").data(); for (var inttt = 0; inttt < oSelectRows.length; inttt++) { sObjektIdListe += ""+oSelectRows[inttt].objektId; `

Comment: `var oSelectRows = oMyTable.rows(".selected").data(); ` `for (var inttt = 0; inttt < oSelectRows.length; inttt++) {` `console.log(" ID "+ oSelectRows[inttt].objektId);` `}` .. how can I format this correctly?

Comment: can you please comment on my post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869730/datatables-editor-filed-type-select-action-for-edit-and-remove-buttons-issues

Answer (score 7):

```
var table = $('#myTableId').DataTable();
var a= [];
$.each(table.rows('.myClassName').data(), function() {
a.push(this["productId"]);
});

console.log(a[0]);
```