# Get all cells from a specific row in JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need get all data from a specific row in datatables. How can I achieve this? I have not found anything in the API documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables Getting selected row values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191760/jquery-datatables-getting-selected-row-values)

Comment: this is pretty easy to look up in the reference manual as well as by doing google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) is what you are looking for:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var rowData = table.row(0).data();
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ze33f1bb/).