# getting datatables multiple selected rows values as an array

Tags: datatables

This question is regarding datatables,

I am trying to get multiple selected rows values as an array but unfortunately it comes as object only,

```js
console.log(table.rows({'.selected').data());

 var ids = jQuery.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
    return item[3];
});

console.log(ids);
```

by using this code I am getting

```js
[object, object, object,context:array[1]....]
[]
```

but i could not get like...

```js
[array, array, array...]
['test','test1']
```

What is wrong with this?
I tried with below question, but i could not get array,
[jQuery DataTables Getting selected row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191760/jquery-datatables-getting-selected-row-values)

Answer (score 5):

You can call toArray(), I could not find this in the docs - I got desperate, just tried it and it worked!

```
table.rows('.selected').data().toArray()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Hours searching and this was the only correct answer I could find. Using the updated syntax: 

table.rows({selected:true}).data().toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using dataTables own [**every()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) iterator method? Here is an example of multi select, where the selected rows is consoled out as array of array of strings :

```js
table.on('select.dt', function() {
   var array = [];
   table.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx) {
      array.push(table.row(rowIdx).data())
   })   
   console.log(array);
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0yvm41q7/**

Comment: When you unselect a checkbox, the row isnt't removed from the array until you carry out the next iteration. Have you a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Blawless, there is no checkboxes used what so ever in the above, and  `array` exists inside the function scope only. So you have lost me here :)...